# Docker as "Function" (Create a Docker per request)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

Is there a simple way to create an istance of a  docker container for each request?

I have a Docker container that takes a very long time to compute a mathematical algorithm. When running, no other requests can be processed in parallel. Lambda Functions would be the best solution, but the container needs to download more than 1gb of data and needs at least 10 cores and 5GB ram to be executed, and therefore Lambda would be too expensive.

We have a big cluster (1000 cores, 0.5TB RAM) and I was considering to use a NGINX Load balancer or a Kubernetes bare metal. 
Is it possible to configure in a way that creates an instance per request (similar to a Lambda Function)?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like Airflow or Argo that are designed for these things.

basically you can create a DAG will run very much like a function as a service but on what ever custom docker container you want.

Comment: My docker container exposes a public API. Can I still use DAG using a single container or do I need to create a kind of API Gateway that then use the DAG to create a container per request?

Comment: if you run this via kubernetes you can spin up pods and not just individual containers, so you con run the apl as a sidecar

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to decouple the HTTP service from the backend processing.  If the job takes minutes or longer to run, most browsers and other HTTP clients will time out before it will finish, so the HTTP end of it needs to start the job in some way and immediately return some sort of success message.

Once you’ve done that, you might find a job queue like RabbitMQ a useful piece of infrastructure technology.  Again, this decouples the queue of jobs from the mechanism to actually run them.  In a Docker/Kubernetes space you’d launch some number of persistent workers that all listened to the queue and did work as it appeared there.  You wouldn’t necessarily launch one worker per job; or possibly you would have just one worker that launched other Docker containers or Kubernetes Jobs; but if the work backlog got too long you could launch additional workers.

In a pure-Docker space it’s theoretically possible to use the Docker API to launch additional containers.  However, doing this gives your process unlimited root-level access to the host; if you are running this in the context of an HTTP server you need to be extremely careful about security considerations.  Kubernetes also has an API and from a security point of view this is probably better: you can set up a service account that has permissions only to launch Jobs, and launch a Job per inbound job that arrives.  (Security is still important but it’s much harder for a malicious input to root the host.)